# PHP won't add my SQL item

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and trying to add a item to my MySQL database.

If I use the following code it works:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `intranet`.`product_form` (`id`, `ProductName`, `ProductInitiatedBy`) VALUES (NULL,  'item1', 'item2')") or die("Could not perform select query - " . mysql_error());;
```

However, if I use the following code it doesn't work:

```
$product_name=("tom"); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `intranet`.`product_form` (`id`, `ProductName`, `ProductInitiatedBy`) VALUES (NULL,  $product_name, 'item2')") or die("Could not perform select query - " . mysql_error());;
```

I get an error that says:

> Could not perform select query - Unknown column 'ProductName1234' in
>   'field list'

The `ProductName1234` is the data from `$product_name` and should be the data I am trying to add and not the column.

Comment: First of all, format your code!

Comment: just did.. i typed [code] and found i did it wrong.. all fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `intranet`.`product_form` (`id`, `ProductName`, `ProductInitiatedBy`) VALUES (NULL,  $product_name, 'item2')") or die("Could not perform select query - " . mysql_error());;
```

to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `intranet`.`product_form` (`id`, `ProductName`, `ProductInitiatedBy`) VALUES (NULL,  '$product_name', 'item2')") or die("Could not perform select query - " . mysql_error());
```

You need to add `'` to `$product_name`:

```
VALUES (NULL,  '$product_name', 'item2')
               ^             ^
```

Comment: I did try that before, but looks like that works as well. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

When you insert strings like that, you need to surround them in quotes, else MySQL will think you are trying to specify a column from somewhere to insert data from.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO intranet.product_form (id, ProductName, ProductInitiatedBy) VALUES (NULL, \"$product_name\", 'item2')");
```